# On Touch screen when i touch input field it does not show onscreen keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows, on-screen-keyboard

Google chrome when i go to input field and touch it. It does not open the on screen windows keyboard.

```
<map name="map_gdpr" class="maps">
    <input type="text" 
           style="position:absolute;top: 179px;
left: 385px;width: 505px;background-color: white;height: 40px;font-size:24px;" 
id="eid_company" name="eid_company" class="input_field" />

    <input type="checkbox" 
           value="on" 
           id="agreement" 
           name="agreement"
           style="position: absolute;
                  top: 318px;
                  left: 283px;
                  width: 38px;
                  background-color: white;
                  height: 58px;"/>


  </map>
```

How to make sure the on screen keyboard from windows is open when input field is touched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a BUG in Google chrome. Google chrome do not have qualified programmer to fix it, but Microsoft Edge works.

Temporary solution for Google chrome was as below:

```
    <input type="checkbox" 
           value="on" 
           id="agreement" 
           name="agreement"
           style="position: absolute;
                  top: 318px;
                  left: 283px;
                  width: 38px;
                  background-color: white;
                  height: 58px;"/>
<map name="map_gdpr" class="maps">
    <input type="text" 
           style="position:absolute;top: 179px;
left: 385px;width: 505px;background-color: white;height: 40px;font-size:24px;" 
id="eid_company" name="eid_company" class="input_field" />



  </map>
```